# convert eastings and northings to latitude and longitude on ios

Tags: ios, latitude-longitude

I have a data set of eastings and northings and I need to convert these to a latitude and longitude value. Does anyone have any idea how to do this on iOS. I have tried using [convert eastings and northings](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html)
 javascript function but I got stuck in an infinite loop in the do while statement.

If anyone has any thoughts or experience on the matter please do share, I would really appreciate it.

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 1):

You need a projection library, and [proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) is a dominant one. Here's a helpful description of using it with iOS:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/how-to-integrate-proj4-into-an-ios-iphone-project

You'll need to know what the source coordinate system is, e.g. UTM, NAD, mercator, etc.

Comment: thanks for the link... Do you have any experience with using this? Or even know how I might go about converting the coordinates? I took a look at the "documentation" and to be completely honest.... I was lost...

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, but with c/c++ not iOS. Start with the description on the [api reference](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/ProjAPI) page. The sequence is to create a `projPJ` instance, call `pj_fwd()` for geo to xy or `pj_inv()` for xy to geo, (all in radians) then `pj_free()`. I see `transform()` has deprecated pj_fwd() and pj_inv(). However, more important is to know what you're transforming from and to. Eastings/Northings means nothing without knowing what the coordinate system is.

Comment: thanks again for your help, I have asked about the coordinate system and am waiting for a response. I will have a look at these functions and see what I can do. I'll let u know about the coordinate system... will this affect how I use the functions then?

Comment: It affects how you initialize: `pj_init()` takes a parameter being a text description of the coordinate system so that it knows how to compute the values.